# How to make a continuous gradient?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have multiple `<a>` and I wanted to have a gradient that goes through all of them without breaking. I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhkrtozb/1/) to be more explicit, in that jsfiddle the gradient is starting and finishing in the same `<a>` but I wanted to begin in the first one and end in the last.

```css
body{
      background: lightgray;
   }
   .tabs{
    margin: 3% 0 0 3%;
 }

 .tab {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#006680, #00b8e6);
    padding: 0.5% 2% 0.5% 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .tab:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<a href="#" class="tab">tab1</a>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab2</a>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab3</a>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab4</a>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab5</a>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Either you make them as one line and make gradient for their parent or you have to calculate these "stop-points" for gradient to make it "continue".

Comment: as @Sergey said and as you said "a gradient that goes through all of them without breaking" : you need to apply it to a parent element

Comment: @Sergey I've already wrapped all <a> in one div (wrapper) and added gradient in wrapper but that does not make gradient only inside the border. So I've added in <a> "visibility: visible" and "background: inherit" and then hidden in wrapper but the background was also gone

Comment: For future reference,  links to external code are discouraged on Stack Overflow as they can be removed or change over time. The preferred way is to use stack snippets directly in the question. See [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I've already added the code into a snippet for you in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on the comment, you can try to work some magic with having a parent background go through all of these links, or you can just write a different gradient for each one that has all of the stop points.

```
.tab:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#00ACD7,#00B8E6);
}
.tab:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#00A1C9,#00ACD7);
}
.tab:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#0095BA,#00A1C9);
}
.tab:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#0089AC,#0095BA);
}
.tab:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#007D9D,#0089AC);
}
.tab:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,#00728F,#007D9D);
}
```

You could probably have this be generated somewhat by Sass using a colour function and a for loop but I'm not sure how specific you'd be able to be.

https://jsfiddle.net/m61es0rv/

btw I got each gradient point from here https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/#006680:00B8E6:6:hex

Comment: That's perfect I didn't knew that site. As @Sergey said in question's comments I was wondering how could I figure those breaking points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

If you want to use a single gradient, you're going to have to give the gradient to the parent element and go from there. I did just that and added some span elements to separate the buttons with the grey background color you chose.

The other option as Sergey rightfully stated would be to chop the gradient up and put different gradients on each block individually.

```css
body{
      background: lightgray;
}

.tabs{
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#006680, #00b8e6);
    display: flex;
}

.tab {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5% 2% 0.5% 2%;
}

.tab:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.separator {
display: inline-block;
width:10px;
background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<a href="#" class="tab">tab1</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab2</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab3</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab4</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab5</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
<a href="#" class="tab">tab6</a>
<span class="separator"></span>
</div>
```